# an error while use sizeof(boost::lockfree::queue<std::string>)

Tags: c++, boost

I got an error about sizeof(boost::lockfree::queuestd::string). My code is as below:

Global.h:

```
extern boost::lockfree::queue<std::string> &imgPendingQueue;

class Initializer
{
// do something
};
```

Global.cpp:

```
#include "Global.h"

static char imgPendingQueueBuf[sizeof(boost::lockfree::queue<std::string>)];

boost::lockfree::queue<std::string> &imgPendingQueue = reinterpret_cast<boost::lockfree::queue<std::string>&>(imgPendingQueueBuf);

// do something
```

While compiling, I got an error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:95:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'boost::has_trivial_destructor<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>::value' "(boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value)"
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value));
    ^                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/static_assert.hpp:70:41: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT'
#     define BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( ... ) static_assert(__VA_ARGS__, #__VA_ARGS__)
                                        ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~
Global.cpp:8:32: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::lockfree::queue<std::__1::basic_string<char>>' requested here
static char imgPendingQueueBuf[sizeof(boost::lockfree::queue<std::string>)];
```

I don't know how to solve the problem. Could somebody provide some help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lockfree::queue<T>` requires `T` to have a trivial destructor (among other requirements, see [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html))

`std::string` is not [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType). Hence `queue<std::string>` is ill-formed and your `reinterpret_cast` trick will not help.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I push a string into a queue? It seems like only basic type, such as Integer is trivial.

Comment: You could push dynamically allocated `char*` and manually deal with freeing up memory. Or use a regular blocking queue (e.g. sync_queue from boost.thread)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Dynamically alllcated char* works fine.